# OSCLASS: something wrong with self::$instance = new self;

Tags: php

I have setup osclass in a directory of my website. When I try to access this directory(index.php), it returns blank page with response status 200. I don't see any error in the apache error log. I also have included these lines and no errors are reported.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

When I tried to examine the php code, I found that the line self::$instance = new self; is not executed in this function:

```
    public static function newInstance()
    {
        if(!self::$instance instanceof self) {
            self::$instance = new self;  //It appears theres a problem with this line
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }
```

This is in class Rewrite. This functions is called from oc-load.php:

$instance is declared private static: private static $instance;

```
if( OC_ADMIN ) {
  ....
  ....
} else {
  // init Rewrite class only if it's the frontend   
  Rewrite::newInstance()->init();   
}
```

I am just beginning with oop php. I understand that the above line is trying to create a new instance of class Rewrite. But I'm not able to find why its not executed.

Can you please tell me why this fails?

Comment: Where is `$instance` declared and is it declared as `static`?

Comment: its declared as private static

Comment: How do you know it's not being called?  What does `var_dump(Rewrite::newInstance());` (before the `->init()` call) show?

Comment: I don't believe your issue resides in `newInstance` function. More debugging will be needed to fully resolve your problem(s). I would try @RocketHazmat's suggestion and test what `Rewrite::newInstance()` returns (if anything)

Comment: I am not sure if I'm doing it right. I just placed an echo statement to trace the problem. If I put the echo statement (echo 'some value';) before the mentioned line I see the 'some value' echoed on the screen. But if I put it after the line then nothing is echoed in the screen.

Comment: In your config.php file (at the root of Osclass), try to add `define('OSC_DEBUG', true);`. It will enable debug in Osclass that might help. :)

Comment: I'm having a blank page without any log too when php reaches `new static();` expression. Did anyone have experienced this issue ? (Using xampp on windows 10, php 5.5.38. That same code runs flawlessly on Ubuntu 15.10, with php5-fpm[php 5.5.9])